# Get list of sub-taxonomies of custom taxonomy in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

As my title, How can i get all sub taxonomies of custom taxonomy(by Id or slug or other)?
example my model:

```
City:

   City-type-1

   City-type-2

   ...
```

I search for may results but cannot find the correct one.

Comment: This has been answered here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74345/get-the-children-of-the-parent-category Try using `child categories` as your search term.

Comment: @JohanPretorius my question may be not clear. I mean Custom Taxonomy. your result is about default category so not compatible to my case.

Comment: You can just change the default category to your custom taxonomy in the code and it will work.

Comment: I used get_terms() and it worked. Thank you.